# open source php search and pagination script?

Tags: php

i have a database full of rows of data.

i need an open source php search and pagination script.

so all i need to do is hook it up to the database, and results will be paginated. also the searching function optimized already....

Comment: Well, I'm in search for an automatic, open source (preferably MIT license) and stable, yet performant but at the same time light-weight, with support for different frameworks and CMSs, and self-generating frontend code, simple to hook up auto webpage generator script in PHP. That would be so cool! I wouldn't need to do any work anymore and would just call a command line script any morning. (Have I mentioned, that it should also have a cool CLI interface?)

Comment: We are not a replacement for Google. Or Bing. Or whatever.

Comment: @Boldewyn: I'd like a copy of your self generating code please!

Comment: i dont know any open source or freeware but there is a software called phpmaker, which does exactly you want (but i'm sure the code it generates will be garbage)

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that if we can find you an open source script like the one you are looking for, but it's not free, you wouldn't be interested?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is so *"freeform"* so my answer is also. Take a look at the Zend Framework Pagintor and Search modules:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Paginator is very good and easy to use. Easy to integrate with somesort of caching and etc, but I have never really used search, so I cant comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

[Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) has exactly what you need. Take a look here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CPagination